# Tomcat server IP address restriction methods?

Tags: tomcat, restriction

I knew that I can add a Valve in context.xml in tomcat server to allow or deny some IP address :

`<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="127\.0\.0\.1" denyStatus="403" />`

Except above configuration, **Are there any other method that I can config IP restriction?**

For example, can I use text file or database to store IP addresses for IP restriction propose?

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can dynamically register Tomcat's Remote Address Filter.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#Remote_Address_Filter

It looks like this:

```
@WebListener
public class MyServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
  @Override
  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    // Get IP addresses from the DB or text file.
    ...

    ServletContext sc = sce.getServletContext();
    FilterRegistration fr;
    fr = sc.addFilter("RemoteAddrFilter", "org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteAddrFilter");
    fr.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST), true, "/*");
    fr.setInitParameter("allow", "127\\.0\\.0\\.1");
    fr.setInitParameter("denyStatus", "403");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!!,  May I know After I built up this class,  How to call this class in context.xml????

Comment: To make the above class work you need Tomcat 7 but you do not need any configuration changes. The above class implements [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) and is annotated with [@WebListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebListener.html). Tomcat automatically detects the class and calls contextInitialized on the webapp startup.

Comment: Thanks again!   Which/Where the file I need to modify actually to add the class **MyServletContextListener** ?    is it **bootstrap.jar** in ***C:\tomcat\bin\***  ?

Comment: or I only need to create a jar file which include the class `MyServletContextListener`  and then put the jar to c:\tomcat\bin  ?

Comment: No, you need to put the class into your webapp (Just like a servlet class).

Comment: Is it means that I should put the class into  `C:\tomcat\webapps\myapps\WEB-INF\lib`?    Thanks! you save my life!!

Comment: You'd be better off putting the class into `WEB-INF/classes`.

Comment: may I know @WebListener is only support tomcat 7?

Comment: `@Weblistner` is part of Servlet 3.0. [Only Tomcat 7 supports Servlet 3.0](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html).